# substituting my function in an expression

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have defined a function as mystep in matlab 2014b, which is the same as heaviside except for mystep(0) which is one instead of 0.5.
Now I would like to substitute my function using subs into an expression but it is not possible. Function is:

```
f(x) = heaviside(x) * x^2;
g(x) = subs(f(x) , heaviside(x) , mystep(x));
g(x) =

heaviside(x)
```

As you see, matlab does not do anything, but if I change mystep with `dirac(x)`, it goes well.

```
g(x) = subs(f(x) , heaviside(x) , dirac(x))

g(x) =

dirac(x)
```

what should I do? is there any way to do this? 
Any other help like showing a way to change the value of heaviside at origin in matlab 2014b might be useful.

The content of `mystep`

```
function Y = mystep(X) 
%//This function is a user-defined unit step function, which has the exact 
%//properties of matlab heaviside function except for the value of function 
%//at zero that is defined as 1. 
Y = heaviside(X); 
if Y==0.5 
    Y=1; 
end
```

Comment: The documentation for `heaviside` [explicitly tells you how to change the value at the origin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/heaviside.html#zmw57dd0e65339)...

Comment: yes, but it is not applicable in matlab 2014b

Comment: How does `mystep` look like?

Comment: function Y = mystep(X)

%This function is a user-defined unit step function, which has the exact
%properties of matlab heaviside function except for the value of function
%at zero that is defined as 1.

Y = heaviside(X);
if Y==0.5
    Y=1;
end

Comment: What do you mean it's not applicable in R2014b? Here's the archived R2014b documentation for [`heaviside`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014b/symbolic/heaviside.html). Also, how have you defined `mystep`?

Comment: Add the definition of `mystep` to the question. Don't post it in the comments.

Comment: @horchler: There is no `sympref` in 2014b

Comment: If the answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and this is no longer an open question. If your question is not answered, please explain what’s missing.

Comment: I found the solution in another place, what do you suggest?

Comment: Write a short answer to your own question and accept it. This way future readers can find your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I have to define a new function in which mystep = round(heaviside(x));
end

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand your problem. The `mystep` function you implemented is not compatible to symbolic math. If you try `mystep(sym(x))` you will see it returns heaviside. That's because a symbolic variable compared to a constant is always false.

The best solution I see is to use this definition for `mystep`

```
syms x
mystep(x)=heaviside(x)+1/2-abs(heaviside(x)-.5);
g(x) = subs(f(x) , heaviside(x) , mystep(x));
```

Resulting in:

```
x^2*(heaviside(x) - abs(heaviside(x) - 1/2) + 1/2)
```

Which does not look nice but implements the intended behaviour.